# Change minSDKVersion depending on Device

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, multiple-versions, android-min-sdk

I want to publish my application for more than one Version of Android.
Thats why I wrote this in my Manifest xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

My app shows a TimePicker. The TimePicker usually looks different in version 4.0.3.
Since I choose version 8 as my default sdk version, the TimePicker looks like the old one, even then I run the app on a 4.0.3 device.

Is there any way to choose sdk version 15 when this app is running on a 4.0.3 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `apk` is only compiled once, so no. Instead, you should set in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

and then check in your code (at runtime) that old devices don't make use of the methods provided in the new framework. For instance,

```
int currentVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;  
if (currentVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
    // It is safe to use the TimePicker.
} else{
    // Don't use the TimePicker (ClassNotFoundException will be thrown).
}
```